# Should nDepend's output folder be added to source control?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, ndepend

### Background

I am new to nDepend and wish to use it on a project that will be maintained with multiple developers in Subversion.

I am quite keen on keeping historic nDepend analysis results and notice that nDepend does that quite well by default by placing such results in the folder defined by `$(NdProjectOutputDir)` - usually a subfolder called **NDependOut** immediately beneath where the .**ndproj** file is located.

[image]

This means however that the generated nDepend XML and binary files are located along with my source code.

[image]

I have read the following articles by nDepend:

- *[Trend Monitoring](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/trend-monitoring?cx=015095677987321916295%3Ar_17mxn8qfg&cof=FORID%3A11&q=source%20control&sa=Search#)*
- *[Logging Trend Metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/trend-monitoring?cx=015095677987321916295%3Ar_17mxn8qfg&cof=FORID%3A11&q=source%20control&sa=Search#Log)*

...and even tried a Google search *["ndepend ndependout source control"](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=ndepend%20ndependout%20source%20control&es_th=1)* which at the time of writing, the latter was not particularly useful for my questions below.

### Questions

1. Should **NDependOut** be added to SCM?  They strike me as essentially output artifacts as the result of the source code in the same way as compiling a project is and should not be added.  But I am not sure that philosophy applies
2. If the **NDependOut** folder is added to source control for the benefit of other users, do I run the risk of conflict?
3. Should we instead nominate one person (or perhaps a build machine) to be the sole publisher of such reports?

I note at that in the root **NDependOut** folder there are two files:

- **NDependAnalysisResult_VIP_2015Jun11_18h33.ndar** - binary
- **InfoWarnings.xml** - text obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed you are quite free to decide. When you wrote:

*This means however that the generated NDepend XML and binary files are located along with my source code.*

...maybe it means you haven't seen the possibility to customize both...

- historic analysis result + report storage root folder,
- and trend metric storage root folders,

...both from *NDepend Project Properties > Analysis*, see screenshots below.

---

To answer your question in reverse order:

3) I'd say that if you choose to store this data in your SCM, **it should be done by your Build Process automatically** after a successful build process + NDepend analysis

2) No there is no risk of conflict on Historic analysis result + reports since they are stored in a hierarchy of folders named after the build date/time. Concerning trend metric yes there is a risk of conflict since the storage is made by one XML file per year.

1)

- It is certainly worth sharing trend metrics with the team through SCM.
- It is certainly worth sharing the baseline for diff analysis result as well through SCM. Typically the baseline for diff represents the last release in production code snapshot.
- It is certainly worth sharing the most recent report generated by the build process (not necessarily through SCM, it should be available through an [url](http://www.ndepend.com/Sample-Reports/OnNDepend/NDependReport.html)).
- Concerning all intermediate analysis result it is up to you, but if they are not used as baseline for diff, probably they will be useless.

---

[image: NDepend Historic Custom Folder Settings]

[image: NDepend Trend Metrics Custom Folder Settings]

Comment: Thanks very much Patrick for your informative answer.  It will go along way with planning our setup